# Como eu faço pra verificar se existe um arquivo?

Tags: php

Usei a função `file_exists` e ela até encontra o arquivo.

O problema é que quando não encontra, não é exibida a mensagem que não existe (não entra no else).

```
<?php
    $email = $v->email;
    $email = strstr($email, '@', true);
    $url = base_url();
    foreach (array('png', 'jpg', 'gif') as $ext) {
        if (!file_exists("./uploads/{$email}." . $ext)) {
            continue;
        }
        $email = "$email.$ext";

        $filename = "./uploads/{$email}";


        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            echo "O arquivo $filename existe";
        } else {
            echo "O arquivo $filename não existe";
        }

        echo "<img alt='' class='left avatar-comentario' src=\"" . $url . "uploads/$email\" maxwidth=\"300\" ,maxheight=\"400\" />";
        break;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso porquê você verifica a existência do arquivo duas vezes e na primeira você executa `continue` caso o arquivo não exista. O `continue` faz com que a iteração atual seja finalizada e, assim, o segundo `if` não é executado.

O que pode fazer é remover o primeiro `if`:

```
foreach (array('png', 'jpg', 'gif') as $ext) 
{
    $email = "$email.$ext";
    $filename = "./uploads/{$email}";

    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        echo "O arquivo $filename existe";
        echo "<img alt='' class='left avatar-comentario' src=\"" . $url . "uploads/$email\" maxwidth=\"300\" ,maxheight=\"400\" />";
        break;
    } else {
        echo "O arquivo $filename não existe";
    }
}
```

Desta forma, iria funcionar, mas apareceria várias mensagens na página. Uma forma interessante de fazer é manter uma imagem de avatar genérica e, se o sistema encontrar o arquivo, substituir a imagem. Algo como:

```
$avatar = "./uploads/avatar.png";

foreach(array("png", "jpg", "gif") as $ext)
{
    $filename = "./uploads/{$email}.{$ext}";

    if (file_exists($filename))
    {
        $avatar = $filename;
        break;
    }
}

echo "<img ... src=\"{$avatar}\" />"
```

Desta forma, se o sistema não encontrar nenhum dos arquivos, é exibido o avatar genério `uploads/avatar.png`, mas se encontrar, exibe a imagem encontrada.

Comment: Obrigado Anderson, sua resposta me ajudou!